# JSON select only certain elements

Tags: jquery, json

I am having a devil of a time with selecting only certain elements in a JSON list.  For the example below, I only want the elements name where max == 0.  I've tried the following select statement, but it returns all elements max == 0 or max == 1.  Any ideas?

**Select Statement:**

```
jq 'select(.[].max == 0)'
```

**Sample JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhdb",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhi",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "0",
    "max": 0,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhr",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhs",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want this in jq or in any other way, but here is a simple way to filter the data by `max === 0`:

```js
let data = [{
    "name": "PATCHING-vhdb",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhi",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "0",
    "max": 0,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhr",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhs",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  if (item.max === 0) {
    result.push(item.name);
  }

  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged jquery...you can user [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "PATCHING-vhdb",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhi",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "0",
    "max": 0,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhr",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhs",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var result = $(data).filter(function(i, n) {
    return n.max === 1
  });

  console.log(result);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascripts [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on the Array , like so:

```js
const jsonArray = [
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhdb",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhi",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "0",
    "max": 0,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhr",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhs",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  }
]

const filteredArray =  jsonArray.filter( el => el["max"] === 0 );

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using JavaScript :**

```js
var jsonObj = [{
  "name": "PATCHING-vhdb",
  "ctm": "controlm-server",
  "available": "1",
  "max": 1,
  "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
 },
 {
  "name": "PATCHING-vhi",
  "ctm": "controlm-server",
  "available": "0",
  "max": 0,
  "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
 },
 {
  "name": "PATCHING-vhr",
  "ctm": "controlm-server",
  "available": "1",
  "max": 1,
  "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
 },
 {
  "name": "PATCHING-vhs",
  "ctm": "controlm-server",
  "available": "1",
  "max": 1,
  "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
 }
];

var res = jsonObj.filter(obj => obj.max === 0);

for (var i in res) {
  console.log("Element Name :", res[i].name);
}
```

**Using JQuery :**

```js
var jsonObj = [{
    "name": "PATCHING-vhdb",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhi",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "0",
    "max": 0,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhr",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "name": "PATCHING-vhs",
    "ctm": "controlm-server",
    "available": "1",
    "max": 1,
    "workloadPolicy": "N/A"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var res = $(jsonObj).filter(function(index, item) {
    return item.max === 0
  });

  console.log("Element name :", res[0].name);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```